# How to register a nested object into react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

While using react hook form, i have a default value like this:

```
  const form = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      username: "aaaaaa",
      social: {
        facebook: "",
        twitter: "",
      },
    },
  });
```

Problem is that, when i do something like
`register("username")` it works, but i can not register nested object's properties. I mean that, even if i give some input, RHF devtools does not react and i get "facebook required" error from the input below

```
<label
  htmlFor="facebook"
>
  Facebook
</label>
<input
  {...register("social.facebook", {
    required: "Facebook required",
  })}
  type="text"
  id="facebook"
  name="facebook"
/>
<p className="text-red-500">{errors.social?.facebook?.message}</p>
```

What should i do? Thanks

Comment: remove `name="facebook"`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"

import './styles.css'

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm()
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data)

  console.log(errors)
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register("username", { required: "username is required" })} />
      <input defaultValue="fb" {...register("social.facebook")} />
      <input {...register("social.twitter", { required: "twitter is required" })} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

clicking submit will log:

```
username: Object
  type: "required"
  message: "Email Address is required2222"
  ref: <INPUT name="username"></INPUT>
social: Object
  twitter: Object
    type: "required"
    message: "Email Address is required"
    ref: <INPUT name="social.twitter"></INPUT>
```

and if you add text it'll log

```
username: "username"
social: Object
  facebook: "fb"
  twitter: "twitter"
```